# Stackview with two table views and labels causes overlap

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've been trying to build the following view that I already built in an Android app:

[image: Android layout]

I used a stack view to layout the views vertically. There is
a label, followed by first table view, then another label, then another table view(Android configuration is the same):

[image: IOS Layout]

What I would expect is to have the first table view stretch to accomodate the 3 items inside, the label after it to follow, and so on without constraining heights.

This is how the autolayout looks like:

[image: Autolayout]

And these are the constraints I set up:

[image: Constraints]

How can I achieve the same view like in Android?

Comment: Can you explain your question more.

Comment: Why you are not trying one tableview with Multiple sections ?

Comment: Can you use multiple section with just one table view ?

Comment: @dahiya_boy I want to have the same layout like in the first image.
Multiple sections did not occur to me.

Comment: What is the stackview's distribution and alignment? From a data perspective, what does the Android app do when if the two tables don't have enough data to populate the full height?

Comment: @AgRizzo If there is less than 3 items the first table view is hidden. The other table view takes as much space as the content needs, and the background color is the same so it looks seamless. Here howerver I am having overlaps.

Comment: @Matsura So in **Your Position** section, there always be top three players??

Comment: @dahiya_boy There can be either three or none. If less than three I hide the whole section

Comment: @Matsura I recommend to use static stackView for upper part which have header (you position : 10) and top 3 players data. Use tableview for leaderboard. It is very easy to implement and handle. If top 3 players have no data then all you need to hide view inside the stackview and that gap is automatically filled by the leaderboard. So you dont need to do extra efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that views based on UIScrollView (all table views and collection views are) don't have an intrinsic size to return to the Stack View; they could theoretically be of infinite size. The correct way to solve this is not to put them in a stack view, but add them as constrained sub-views with the following constraints:

- Top table view is constrained equal to the top, leading, and trailing edges of its superview.
- Bottom table view is constrained equal to the bottom, leading, and trailing edges of its superview.
- Top table view's bottom anchor is equal to the top anchor of the bottom table view.
- Top and bottom table views are constrained to have equal heights.

That will force the table views to each use half of the available screen space, while remaining flexible for different screen sizes.

Comment: This seems like a possible solution. What about the constraints on the label positions(Your position, Leaderboard)?

Comment: Oh sure, just insert them between the top of the top table and the top of the superview, and between the top and bottom tables, respectively. The tables should shrink equally to accommodate them.